# mySQL query explanation needed

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `sampledata`.`ORDERFACT` (
  `ORDERNUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRODUCTCODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUANTITYORDERED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRICEEACH` decimal(17,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORDERLINENUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOTALPRICE` decimal(17,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORDERDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `REQUIREDDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHIPPEDDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENTS` longtext,
  `CUSTOMERNUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_ID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTR_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YEAR_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_ORDERFACT_lookup` (`ORDERNUMBER`,`PRODUCTCODE`,`QUANTITYORDERED`,`PRICEEACH`,`ORDERLINENUMBER`,`TOTALPRICE`,`ORDERDATE`,`REQUIREDDATE`,`SHIPPEDDATE`,`STATUS`,`CUSTOMERNUMBER`,`TIME_ID`,`QTR_ID`,`MONTH_ID`,`YEAR_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Can someone explain me what will do the last three lines:

```
(KEY `idx_ORDERFACT_lookup` ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

(KEY `idx_ORDERFACT_lookup` ...)

will create a composite primary key on all the columns in the bracket.

If you want to learn more read [MySQL :: MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 7.5.2 Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

**Addendum:**

Actually if you are designing this table I might have few suggestions for you:

1. It is more cross-platform compatible to use small letters in columns names for some systems/dbrms are not case sensitive
2. `PRICEEACH`... do you really need to store 5 decimal places for price? And then `TOTALPRICE` has 0 decimal positions...
3. Those `monthid, quarterid` itd look sort of weird, especially being `BIGINT` but probably you have a requirement for that.

Just a few thoughts.

Comment: It is not a `PRIMARY KEY`. It's a simple `KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

(KEY `idx_ORDERFACT_lookup` ...) will add an index to the table.

If you really want to dig deep then visit:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

It is 12.1.10 topic. Focus on third grey box. You will get something like this:
{INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_type]
Everything is square brackets is optional.

Hope it helps!!!